# Changing template file checkout success page issue

Tags: layout, blocks, magento-1, template, onepage-checkout

This is my layout:

```
<checkout_onepage_success translate="label">
        <label>One Page Checkout Success</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="kryd_checkout_success" template="kryd/success.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_success>
```

I want to change the core/template to access my block from my custom module. This is my block path:

```
app/code/community/KRYD/Observer/Block/Checkout/Success.php
```

This is my block content:

```
<?php
class KRYD_Observer_Block_Checkout_Success extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Success
{

}
```

This is my block declaration from my config.xml:

```
<global>
        <blocks>
           <KRYD_Observer>
               <class>KRYD_Observer_Block</class>
           </KRYD_Observer>
        </blocks>
</global>
```

If i leave the core/template I get the content from my new template file.
These are what I tried:

```
<block type="observer/checkout_success" name="kryd_checkout_success" template="kryd/success.phtml"/>
```

or

```
<block type="kryd_observer/checkout_success" name="kryd_checkout_success" template="kryd/success.phtml"/>
```

If I leave the `kryd_observer` , it doesn't load any template. Smth I missed. Can you help me with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your block declaration in your `config.xml` with the following:

```
<global>
        <blocks>
           <kryd_observer>
               <class>KRYD_Observer_Block</class>
           </kryd_observer>
        </blocks>
</global>
```

The block namespace is case sensitive.

PS: and this code will work:

```
<block type="kryd_observer/checkout_success" name="kryd_checkout_success" template="kryd/success.phtml"/>
```